# Use an html button to pass elements to an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to be able to create an array with the elements I declare on a html button. The button ask the name of my friends and I should be able to input them and at the same time create one array with all of my friends names.
thanks!
F

Comment: Where's your attempt? This shows no minimal understanding

Comment: Please post something you have so far, to give us an idea of what you are actually trying to achieve.  The question is vague and unclear.

Comment: I think you have to post your working first. Look like you want anyone to do it for you :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so I'll add my 2 cents as a reply.  I would add one more line to pnellesen's code:

```
$('#name').val("");
```

This way, the field will clear every time you click the Add Name button.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking, something like this, using JQuery:

Javascript:

```
var nameArray = new Array();
$('#formsubmit').click(function () {
nameArray.push($('#name').val());
$('#resultdiv').html(nameArray.toString());
});
```

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm">
 <input id="name" type="text"/> <input type="button" id="formsubmit" value="Add name"/>
</form>
<div id="resultdiv"></div>
```

[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/pnellesen/L6Pd5/)